# How to enter more than 1 value in an array in C/AL Microsoft NAV?

Tags: navision

I want to enter more than one value in an array in C/AL without having to use many lines.
It will only set the values in a array like this:

```
numbers[1] := 5;
numbers[2] := 20;
numbers[3] := 12;
numbers[4] := 9;
```

But I want to know if there is any Java-like way to introduce them like this:

```
int[] numbers = {5, 20, 12, 9};
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You can't do things like that in neither c/al nor al.

There are tons of syntax sugar that won't work in Nav like in other mature languages. So if you new one, just run.